# Customize styling for material paginator

Tags: angular, angular-material, paginator

[custom paginator style](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qaPzZ.png)Is it possible to style the angular material paginator like in this link?

I have tried to overwrite the CSS but unable to do it. can you please suggest a better way to achieve this.

Comment: Yes it is, what have you tried so far? Please share code.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tjhkpo-fdkekb?file=app/table-pagination-example.css tried in this way. But i am not sure how to edit mat-select-box styles to look like horizontal list

Comment: You do not have to use the drop down, you can create your own event to change the qty of items on the page using `@Input() pageSize: number`

Comment: If possible, can you give me some reference to it. very much appreciated.

Comment: Have a look at https://material.angular.io/components/paginator/api